# Using OWl in XML Syntax. First Steps

Tags: rdf, owl

I just started using OWL for a project at the university.
The project is about pizza, which seems to be a common problem when it comes to RDF and OWL. So what we have to do first is model a pizza that consists of two toppings: tomatoes and cheese. I used the property `madeof` to connect them. This is a minimal code snippet that I tried to validate at: http://www.mygrid.org.uk/OWL/Validator

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns="http://example.org/pizzeria#">

    <owl:Ontology rdf:about=""/>  

    <!-- ========================= -->



    <owl:Class rdf:ID="Topping"/>

    <Topping rdf:ID="Cheese"/>
    <Topping rdf:ID="Tomato"/>

     <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="madeOf">
            <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Topping"/>
            <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Pizza"/>
     </owl:ObjectProperty>

     <!-- Pizza -->
     <owl:Class rdf:ID="Pizza">
         <!-- comes with Cheese and Tomato -->
         <rdfs:subClassOf>
                 <owl:Restriction>
                     <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#madeOf"/>
                     <owl:hasValue rdf:resource="#Tomato"/>
                 </owl:Restriction>
         </rdfs:subClassOf>
         <rdfs:subClassOf>
             <owl:Restriction>
                 <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#madeOf"/>
                 <owl:hasValue rdf:resource="#Cheese"/>
             </owl:Restriction>
         </rdfs:subClassOf>
     </owl:Class>
 </rdf:RDF>
```

However, the validator tells me:

OWL DL
Individual Value: restriction(a:madeOf value (a:Cheese))
Individual Value: restriction(a:madeOf value (a:Tomato))

OWL Full
Untyped Class: http://example.org/pizzeria#Topping

Which means, I guess, that the `Toppings` class was not defined (I think I did this…) and that something is wrong with the `madeof` property.  I think I am doing something wrong here and am pretty much stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your OWL is fine, the only problem you have is with the XML encoding of RDF. Generally speaking, avoid working directly with RDF/XML if you can. Turtle is a much more compact and readable syntax, and has fewer gotchas than RDF/XML.

So the gotcha that you fell into is that, while you did define the expansion for the empty prefix:

```
xmlns="http://example.org/pizzeria#"
```

you didn't define the base URI for the document. Subject resources like:

```
<Topping rdf:ID="Cheese"/>
```

will be interpreted as relative to the base URI, rather than as though they had a default blank prefix. See paragraph one, above!

The fix is to define the base URI as well as the default prefix:

```
<rdf:RDF
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns="http://example.org/pizzeria#"
 xml:base="http://example.org/pizzeria#"
>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped a lot to further understand what i am doing :). What about the logical errors that occured on the DL layer?

Comment: It's just telling you that a `hasValue` restriction is outside of OWL Lite, but part of OWL DL. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-owl-features-20040210/#s2.1) for details. Unless you have a particular need to target OWL Lite (unlikely), set your validator for OWL DL. The distinction between DL and Full is more likely to be an issue for you.

Comment: I see. Just read about that. Thank you very much. Think I can do the rest of the project now :)